# Create a joined string of the field-values of an object-list using streams and java8

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a class like

```
public class Person {

  public Person(String firstName) {...}

  public String getFirstname() {...}

  // ... some other fields

}
```

and a list of objects of those class:

```
List<Person > objList = new ArrayList<>();
objList.add(new Person("Peter"));
objList.add(new Person("James"));
objList.add(new Person("Bart"));
```

Now I need a comma-separated-list of the firstnames of this object-list, like `"Peter,James,Bart"`.

How can I do this using lambdas and streams of Java 8? TIA!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's basically the third example in the API documentation for [java.util.stream.Collectors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html):

```
String result = objList.stream()
    .map(Person::getFirstName)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

Comment: Thank you! And sorry for not seeing it in the API docs. I have read many of them and many tutorials, but I missed that one ...

Comment: @nosid I came up with this way too, but it print , at the end how can I avoid it ? objList.stream().map((s) -> s + ",").forEach(System.out::print);